# how to refactor code for form threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, refactoring

in my main form, i have a timer which update the value in the text box every few seconds, the code are the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static int column = 2;
    static int row = 100;
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[,] textbox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[column, row];

    delegate void StringParameterDelegate(int j, string value);
    DisplayTimer displayTimer = new DisplayTimer();
    System.Threading.TimerCallback displayCallback;
    System.Threading.Timer displayTimerThread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

             //set the array for name and update time 

        for (int k = 0; k < column; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
            {
                textbox[k, j] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                textbox[k, j].Size = new Size(160, 18);
                textbox[k, j].Name = "textbox_" + k + "_" + j;

                if (j >= 100)
                {
                    textbox[k, j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point((k * 160) + 20, (j * 18) + 30);
                }

                textbox[k, j].Visible = true;
                Controls.Add(textbox[k, j]);
            }
        }

        displayCallback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(timeDisplay);
        displayTimerThread = new System.Threading.Timer(displayCallback, displayTimer, 3000, 3000);
                // more code
    }

    public void timeDisplay(object timerObject)
    {
        DisplayTimer t = (DisplayTimer)timerObject;  

        for (int j = 0; j < t.row; j++)
        {
            string value = t.outputTime[j].ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            writeToTextBox(j, value);
        }
    }

    public void writeToTextBox(int j, string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new StringParameterDelegate(writeToTextBox), new object[] { j, value });
            return;
        }
        // Must be on the UI thread if we've got this far
        textbox[1, j].Text = value;
    }
```

now the above code runs fine and no error occurs. However i have 3 forms in my program use the same method timeDisplay and writeToTextBox, i have to duplicate the code 3 times in the form. I have tried to refactor the 2 methods and put it into a new class. i got the following errors for my writeToTextBox method.

> Error 1   The name 'InvokeRequired' does not exist in the current
>   context
>
> Error 2   The name 'BeginInvoke' does not exist in the current context
>
> Error 3   The name 'textbox' does not exist in the current context

how do i refactor it effectively? some working snippet of code would be very helpful, thanks in advance

EDIT: below is the correct code for the question: it runs fine without any error. Thanks Tudor

```
class DisplayTimer
{
    public int numberOfRow = 0;
    public int column = 0;
    public DateTime[] outputTime;
    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[,] textbox;
    delegate void StringParameterDelegate(TextBox textbox, string value);

    public void timeDisplay(object timerObject)
    {
        DisplayTimer t = (DisplayTimer)timerObject;

        for (int j = 0; j < t.numberOfRow; j++)
        {
            string value = t.outputTime[j].ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

            if (value != "0001/01/01 00:00:00.000")
            {
                writeToTextBox(textbox[column, j], value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeToTextBox(TextBox textbox, string value)
    {
        if (textbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textbox.BeginInvoke(new StringParameterDelegate(writeToTextBox), new object[] { textbox, value });
            return;
        }
        // Must be on the UI thread if we've got this far
        textbox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move your method outside the `Form1` class you'll need to add at least the control as a parameter to the method, since `BeginInvoke` and `InvokeRequired` are called on `this`. you can just pass the textbox array and call the invokes on it:

```
public void writeToTextBox(int j, string value, TextBox[,] textBoxes)
{
    TextBox textBox = textBoxes[1, j];
    if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox.BeginInvoke(new StringParameterDelegate(writeToTextBox), new object[] { j, value, textBoxes });
        return;
    }
    // Must be on the UI thread if we've got this far
    textBox.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: i try to follow you answer, if i use   public void writeToTextBox(int j, string value, Form1 form), then the parameters are not general enough for 3 different forms (Form1, Form2 and Form3) so i need 3 separate methods anyway. is it true?

Comment: @Clayton Leung: Do all the forms need the `int` and `string` parameters?

Comment: That example won't work, because Form does not have member "textbox". Maybe you meant Form1.  Probably better to pass Textbox instead of Form, since you don't really care about the Form and it makes the design more reusable.

Comment: @MarkLakata Part of the utility of the method is pulling the textbox out of the array, which is lost if you just pass it as a parameter.  Additionally you can't pass `Form1` as then it wouldn't work from the other two forms (which is the point).

Comment: I don't think you want to pass Form at all! Just Textbox. Textbox supports InvokeRequired and BeginInvoke too (as do all Controls)

Comment: thank you very much, i will never get this by myself if i dont get help. i have update the correct code above

Answer (score 0):

InvokeRequired and BeginInvoke need the proper namespaces (using...).

textbox is variable of the Forms class which needs to be passed into your new class.